# Redirect to 404 Page in hash mode

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router

I am using hash mode in vue-router.

I am trying to redirect the user to 404 page which I designed when the wrong URL is entered. 
When user enters something wrong after '#', it works correctly and user is redirected to 404 page.
The problem occurs when we remove the hash from URL and then enter something wrong, the user is not redirected to 404 page.

Here is the part of my router.js file:

```
const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '*',
            name: '404_error',
            component: error_404,
            meta:{
                requiresAuth:true
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the `#` in the URL can be dealt with 100% by Vue because the same page is fetched from the web server. If, instead, you change the path of the URL, then the web server will attempt to fetch the webpage at a different location. This situation needs to be dealt with by the server.

Though you aren't using HTML5 history mode, for your situation the server still needs to be configured to serve your webpage at any path.

I suggest you read the [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) section in the docs.

I'm not familiar with Apache, but maybe something like this will help:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ #$1 [NE,R,L]
```